# Material-ui dialog is not closing when overlay is clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui's dialog.  When the overlay is clicked, `handleClose` is not called. When the "Esc" button is pressed, it is called.

I've injected tap events.  What else is wrong?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

// Tap event required
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

class MyComponent extends Component {
  handleClose(){ 
    console.log('I will be closed');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Modal test</h1>

        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
          <Dialog
            title="Test Dialog"
            modal={false}
            open={(this.props.active)}
            onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
            autoScrollBodyContent={true}>
            Hello world, I'm a dialogue.
          </Dialog>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: you meant with "When the overlay is clicked" is you click the dialog box overlay itself?

Comment: When I click the overlay (the grayed out part of the screen) handleClose is not called.  I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: it won't close but you should see the console log on the browser.

Comment: Strange, I wonder if some dependency or something is wrong... thanks for checking

Comment: nothing logged on browser console? to close it, the 'open' attribute of your Dialog should be equal to something you can change. you can put 'open' as a boolean attribute in your state and change its value in handleClose()

Comment: I cant see any bindings to class method. Did you try  :   {()=> this.handleClose()}

Comment: For me the v1 Dialog just doesn't call onClose on click away. Have tried deleting + reintalling. Seeing it on v1.0.0-beta.31 and v1.0.0-beta.23 both.

Comment: This may be a scoping issue; a similar issue happens using Material-UI's Modal component when the open handler (e.g. triggered by onClick), is on a parent element, rather than a sibling to the element containing the close handler. Moving the open handler to a sibling element allows the closing functionality.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I just tried it out and it works fine. Is there any other code relevant to this? Maybe re-install material ui and try again.

Comment: Thanks for trying it Hussein - I suspect it's a dependency issue, checking it out.

Comment: maybe you have to have a state variable defined for open flag internal to the component?

Answer (score 5):

you must define **onClose** prop for dialog. as you can see:

```
const [opendialog , setOpendialog] = React.useState(false);
const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpendialog(true);
};
const handleClose = () => {
    setOpendialog(false);
}
return (
    <>
    <Button onClick={handleOpen}>open dialog!</Button>
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>
            <Typography>
                are you sure?
            </Typography>
        </DialogTitle>
        <Button onClick={handleClose}>No</Button>
    </Dialog>
    </>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a function for closing the dialog, and send it with prop `onClose` to `Dialog` component.

One thing you have to keep in mind, is that, props `disableBackdropClick` should not be passed to `Dialog` component.

The sample code is as follow

```
    <Dialog
        open = { props.open }
        // disableBackdropClick
        onClose = {(event, reason) => {
            if (props.onClose) {
                props.onClose(event, reason);
            }
        }}
        >
        { ...props.children }
    </Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to specs you should not have to do this, but you can use the following property to force close :

```
<Dialog onBackdropClick={YOUR_CLOSE_FUNCTION_HERE} />
```